# Using Multiple Timers in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I want to use multiple timers in Visual Studio 2012 to read data from multiple registers in a PLC (Programmable Logic Controller, Electronics Stuff). I get proper data when i use only one timer to read one register but when i want read another register, none of the received data is displayed properly (it fluctuates from 0 to actual value). I used a library from my friend to achieve this. So i am not aware of the library..
Here's the code:

```
Imports Communication

Public Class Form1
    Dim plc As PLCEthernetReadWrite

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        plc = New PLCEthernetReadWrite("192.168.1.5")
        Timer1.Start()
        Timer2.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = plc.ReadWord("404507") 'Where 404507 is register no.
        Label4.Text = Val(Label1.Text) / 100
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Label1.Text = plc.ReadWord("002071") 'Where 002071 is register no.
        Label4.Text = Val(Label1.Text) / 100
    End Sub
End Class
```

If i use only one timer (either timer1 or timer2), then i get proper value. But i want to display multiple values from multiple registers.

Comment: why cant you move the code from one timer tick to the other and read both at once?

Comment: Hmm, there's little reason to assume you don't get the actual value.  A common problem with simplistic PLCs is that the host interface is not synchronized with the logic scan.  So you'll observe intermediate values.  If the timing is a little off then you'll see something else.  Use a telephone, call whatever programmer knows something about "PLCEthernetReadWrite".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. I figured it out, the problem was with timing. I increased the timer interval to 200ms from 100ms and everything was working fine. Then i added a third plc.ReadWord and again the program started to misbehave. Then i again increased the timer interval to 300ms and again everything was working well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that there is threading issue going on. Try to avoid calling plc.ReadWord simultaneously.

```
    Private plcLock As New Object

    Private Function GetPlcValue(plc As PLCEthernetReadWrite, word As String) As String
        SyncLock plcLock
            Return plc.ReadWord(word)
        End SyncLock
    End Function

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        Label1.Text = GetPlcValue(plc, "404507") 'Where 404507 is register no.
        Label4.Text = Val(Label1.Text) / 100
    End Sub

    Private Sub Timer2_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Label1.Text = GetPlcValue(plc, "002071") 'Where 002071 is register no.
        Label4.Text = Val(Label1.Text) / 100
    End Sub
```